How to use Node-Modules in GO + Templ Web-App
I'm trying to create a webproject based on go + templ and serve HTML directly from the server. As a frontend I want to use UI5 Webcomponents. So the application feels native for SAP Customers.
I can't make this run, because UI5 Webcomponents doesn't offer CDN import. So what have I tried:
Create a Path: "assets/" and install UI5-Webcomponents via npm in there. The Path is also made public on the webserver and that already works with htmx.js.
Import the script within the base templ:
templ Base() {
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" >
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <title>xRM</title>
            <script type="module" src="/assets/node_modules/@ui5/webcomponents/dist/Button.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/htmx.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body >
            <main >
                { children... }
            </main>
        </body>
    </html>

But the button isn't shown (only text) and chrome tells me the following:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier
"@ui5/webcomponents-base/dist/UI5Element.js". Relative references must
start with either "/", "./", or "../".

For me it sounds like the components are referencing each other internally with relative path and my webserver can't solve this.
Someone has an idea, how to overcome this?
